# C# Replace HEX in binary file

Tags: c#, binary, replace, hex

I have a binary file, where are a few values what should be changed.
To be more exact, at two part of the file, in the beginning, there are two HEX values

```
66 73 69 6D 35 2E 36 39
```

what should be changed to

```
4D 53 57 49 4E 34 2E 31
```

How could I do this async, and as fast as possible? I've got to the point where I read the whole file into a byte[] array, but this class has no search or replace feature.

Comment: Why does it need to be done asynchronously? Can you just run the code in its own thread?

Comment: Why do you want to change the Floppy Disk Boot Record? Are you a virus writer or an anti-virus writer? :-)

Comment: You may find it weird, but it is a Symbian project :D
Actually I want to convert FSIM UDA images to editable MSWIN images, and vice versa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method I wrote which you can use to find where in your `byte[]` the bytes are that you are trying to find.

```
/// <summary>
/// Searches the current array for a specified subarray and returns the index
/// of the first occurrence, or -1 if not found.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sourceArray">Array in which to search for the
/// subarray.</param>
/// <param name="findWhat">Subarray to search for.</param>
/// <param name="startIndex">Index in <paramref name="sourceArray"/> at which
/// to start searching.</param>
/// <param name="sourceLength">Maximum length of the source array to search.
/// The greatest index that can be returned is this minus the length of
/// <paramref name="findWhat"/>.</param>
public static int IndexOfSubarray<T>(this T[] sourceArray, T[] findWhat,
        int startIndex, int sourceLength) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    if (sourceArray == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sourceArray");
    if (findWhat == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("findWhat");
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > sourceArray.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    var maxIndex = sourceLength - findWhat.Length;
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= maxIndex; i++)
    {
        if (sourceArray.SubarrayEquals(i, findWhat, 0, findWhat.Length))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

/// <summary>Determines whether the two arrays contain the same content in the
/// specified location.</summary>
public static bool SubarrayEquals<T>(this T[] sourceArray,
        int sourceStartIndex, T[] otherArray, int otherStartIndex, int length)
        where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    if (sourceArray == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sourceArray");
    if (otherArray == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("otherArray");
    if (sourceStartIndex < 0 || length < 0 || otherStartIndex < 0 ||
        sourceStartIndex + length > sourceArray.Length ||
        otherStartIndex + length > otherArray.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (!sourceArray[sourceStartIndex + i]
            .Equals(otherArray[otherStartIndex + i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sadly not working, even if I create a new class for it, it won't find the SubarrayEquals functions :S

Comment: @fonix232: It’s in my code. Are you sure you copied all of it?

Comment: Yea, I'm sure, copied it into my code (don't know if it matters, but it's a Win Console app, copied functions to Main()) and at 
    if (sourceArray.SubarrayEquals(i, findWhat, 0, findWhat.Length))
it tells me Array has no such function "SubarrayEquals".

Comment: @fonix232: The methods are extension methods. You have to put them into a *public static class*. Sorry I didn’t mention that. Alternatively, you can just change the call to `if (SubarrayEquals(sourceArray, i, findWhat, 0, findWhat.Length))`.

Comment: @fonix232: You're probably using C# 2.0 , which don't support Extension Methods.

Comment: @Claus: Surely then he would get an error pointing to the “this” keyword instead of the call.

Comment: Nope, I am using C# 4.0! But finally solved by the second method you mentioned Timwi, thank you very much! It is working now, now I get the index of the stuff :D