# Update a binary file in ascii method in c#

Tags: c#, binary, hex

I have some fixed hex values to be updated to a binary file. I read the binary file using a hex editor and i found that it needs an updation programattically.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(AsciifileName, FileMode.Open,    FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        stream.Position = i;
        stream.WriteByte(arrayval);
    }
```

I tried using this but i couldnot manage the write as it is showing mis alignment.

I have a *list* with hexa values like

> 27 58 30 34 30 31 32 02

i want it to update at 2nd position as :

> 27 **66** 30 34 30 31 32 02

Is there somebody who is familiarized with this issue?.

**Steps needed **

1. Convert an Binary to Ascii
2. Update the Ascii file with my ascii
   values
3. Convert back to binary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Replace HEX in binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741010/c-sharp-replace-hex-in-binary-file)

Comment: This question has been asked many times

Comment: Is it the file contents that you want to change? I mean, is the goal just to change the file? Is it always the second byte (offset 1)?